# Help with system.stackoverflowexception

Tags: .net, stack-overflow, web-services

All of a sudden my app is handing this out in the application event viewer:

EventType clr20r3, P1 w3wp.exe, P2 6.0.3790.3959, P3 45d6968e, P4 app_code.ahowircm, P5 0.0.0.0, P6 4b167253, P7 30, P8 0, P9 system.stackoverflowexception, P10 NIL.

Nothing has changed since yesterday, and everything worked fine before. The server is running some .net 2.0 webservices on top of Windows Server 2003.!!!!!

**Edit:**

Also I'm running this on two servers, 2008R2 and 2003, the exact same code, on 2008R2 it works fine, but on 2003 it stops the application pool.

Comment: Would you be able to post some of your web service code (perhaps a few web methods) so we can see what your web service is doing?

Comment: Yeah, don't put anything like 'urgent' in the title. This is not a paid support site and no-one is going to drop everything and help you just because you're having an emergency.

Comment: @Tim - Sorry I can't post the source code.
@Chris - Thanks for ur help.
@Ruben - It's actually code related

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This usually points to a runaway recursive call (on purpose or not). Hard to tell without seeing some code.

Comment: I agree sounds like a recursive set or get from a page property.

Comment: It was a recursive call within a method that is rarely used.

Answer (score 6):

Not really an answer, more of a "related interesting info" on those CL20r3 event logs entries.

CLR20r3 explaination

P1 Application Name

P2 Application version

P3Application time stamp

P4 Assembly/Module name

P5 Assembly/Module version

P6 Assembly/Module timestamp

P7 MethodDef

P8 IL offset

P9 Exception name

You could use ILDASM on P1, search for a MethodDef of 060000xx (where xx is P7), to get the method throwing.

Then use reflector to see the code, view it in IL mode and find the line of IL at P8.

Often it will point you directly to the line that threw the exception.

Comment: That's IIS which is expected for a web application

Comment: You wan't me to run Refection on w3wp, I thought it was my web app that was causing the problem, not a but in IIS. I'm I missing something?

Comment: Well no, in this case you don't really want to be disassembling w3wp.exe.  I was just providing a bit of related info to the type of error you were getting.  In this instance a stack overflow is most probably a recursive issue, although, without code??

app_code.ahowircm will the compiled dll for a particular page on your website.  Should be in the bin directory.

Comment: I see nothing named ahowircm anywhere

Comment: try 
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files" 
in there somewhere would be the dynamically compiled class.  Throw that into reflector see if that gives you more of an idea as to where things are messing up.

Are you unable to replicate in VS2005/8

Comment: If you're wondering how to "search for a MethodDef," head on over to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9465990/1001100)

Comment: P8 is 0 and P7 have 4 caracters am i doing thing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your code may not have changed, but chances are your data has. See if any data added recently will cause odd conditions to occur.

Comment: Agreed, sounds like unexpected data

Answer (score 1):

You really need a full stack trace to figure out what's going on.  Are you logging your exceptions anywhere?  If not, you can quickly [wireup an event handler](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/961301/Global-Exception-Handling-with-ASPNET.htm).

Answer (score 0):

This is problem related with loop hole parsing problem. Like I have good example for you,so you can understand easily:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using AddFunction;

namespace sharat
{
public class Program
{
public class A
{
  public  A()
    {
        object obj = new B();
    }
}
public  class B
{
   public  B()
    {
        object obj = new A();
    }

 }



    public  static void Main(string[] args)

    {
      //  long i = 10;
      //  Console.Write(i.ToString());
      //  object obj = i;
      //  Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
      //  i++;

      //Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
      //i++;
      ////obj = i;
      //Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
      //Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
      //Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
      long a = 9;
      long b = 130;

      long d = Add.add(a,b);
        Console.WriteLine(d);
        Console.ReadLine();
        object test = new B();
        Console.WriteLine(d);
     }
    }
   }
```