# How to figure out method name by assembly and methoddef?

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008

Application that was developed on machine with Windows XP and works there just fine has severe problems on target machine with Windows Server 2008. Namely, it fails to start properly with following information avaiable:

```
Description:

  Stopped working


Problem signature:

  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3

  Problem Signature 01: neolant.asrm.rcpfreshner.service

  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.7.0

  Problem Signature 03: 4f4b66d2

  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib

  Problem Signature 05: 2.0.0.0

  Problem Signature 06: 4bf4c743

  Problem Signature 07: e47

  Problem Signature 08: 20e

  Problem Signature 09: Exception

  OS Version:   6.0.6002.2.2.0.272.7

  Locale ID:    1049
```

I would like to extract all possible information from this, which means i need to know what method in mscorlib has methoddef of e47.

How can i retrieve this information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ildasm` (Microsoft Intermediate Language Disassembler). Open the assembly in ildasm, and select `View -> MetaInfo -> Show!` from the main menu. You will see the assembly metadata with *Def/*Ref identifiers.

Comment: Thanks to the tool you pointed out i found the code that error details desribed. Turns out it clears the stack and rethropws exception caught somewhere in System.Runtype.CreateInsanceImpl (one with 5 parameters). Now to somehow gt hold of that exception and figure out from its stack what is to blame...

Answer (score 1):

Navreen has a good description of how to decode the "Watson Bucket" dump here.

http://naveensrinivasan.github.io/2010/11/17/decoding-clr20r3-.net-exception---using-mono-cecil/

He also has a script that uses Mono Cecil to automatically decode the Watson Bucket into a IL dump of where the problem occurred.